# Where to put the look up field

Tags: lookup, relationships

If I want to relate a custom object to the contact object such that the custom object will show in a related list in contacts.

On which object do I make the lookup field, the contact object or custom object or can I do it on either object?

Also, whichever gets the lookup field, is that the parent object of this relationship with respect to code? i.e. contact__r.customobjectfield? or the other way around?

Comment: you need to create lookup in your custom object so it will display in contact object's related list..

Comment: The other way won't work? Also, who is the parent?

Comment: contact will be parent and your custom object will be child

Comment: So this would work? contact__r.customobjectfield?

Comment: BTW, you answered first so if you make this answer I'll mark is as one.

Comment: so when you create a lookup in child custom object that may be `contact__c`.. please goahead and accept Mr.Frodo answer that is the best explanation :) let me know if you need any clarification Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related list is always of childs. That means that record is related to which all child records.So you need to create lookup in the child or to whose related list you want to show.

In your case it is the custom object.

**The object on which you create lookup is always the child.**

For more information see [Understanding Relationship Names](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm)